# Pandas Fix a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an **input_df** full of cases +20k which gets tested and converted into **output_df**.

Some of the cases from **input_df** fail then we get a FAIL output on the output_df.
If that's the case we need to fix the input_df (old) and regenerate a new one input_df(new).
So the final result we seek is **input_df(new)**
The way we fix it is by simply changing the date in the input_date for the cases which have failed.
We know the cases which failed because the output_df has FAIL or SUCCESS in the output_result column.

#sample example below - the actual df are more than 20k rows
ie:

output_df

```
case_id        output_date        carBrand     ouput_result
1                 01/20/21             001          FAIL
2                 02/21/21             002          SUCCESS  
3                 02/08/20             003          FAIL 
4                 01/07/20             001          FAIL
5                 09/05/20             002          SUCCESS
```

input_df (old)

```
case_id    input_date         carBrand 
    1          01/20/21             001  
    2          02/21/21             002 
    3          02/08/20             003
    4          01/07/20             001
    5          09/05/20             002
```

new expected result after the fix (changing dates) =>

input_df (new)

```
case_id   input_date              carBrand 
    **1          01/13/21             001**  
    2          02/21/21             002 
    **3          02/22/20             003**
    **4          01/28/20             001**
    5          09/05/20             002
```

input_df and output_df have matching column case_id.
We need to do the following

1. get the rows **case_id** from output_df with FAIL status
2. match those rows with the rows in the input_df using the **case_id**
   For instance above we see case_id 1,3,4 have failed. Therefore we go to the input_df and look for
   those rows 1,3,5.
   => the failure is because of a wrong date; therefore we need to select a new date within +- 7 days
   multiple of the old one. So if the old date was 01/20/2020 on the original input_df the new test date
   we choose could 01/27/2020
   Or another multiple of +- 7 days. ie: 14,21,28,35..
3. Now, we need to do a groupBy(input_carID) i.e: inputID is a group of cases.
   We do this because we need to fix the cases by not introducing duplicate values at the groupLevel.
   Think of this as a group of Mercedez, or group of Ford, McLaren, etc...
   So when we select a new date for the FAIL case we need to check all the cases within a certain group
   that the date we selected was not already selected before.
   => So we make a group of each car brand groupBy() and we then fix the cases in each group which failed.

When we have gone through all the FAIL cases within each group, we now have a new input_df (new).

The fix is about changing the date in the input_df (old) and therefore getting a new one input_df (new)
This is what I have so far which is not working. I do not get unique values for the input_df and also the input_df gets printed 3 times for some reasons..

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime
    
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "case_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "output_date": ["2021-01-20", "2021-02-21", "2020-02-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-09-05"],
    "output_carId": ["001", "001", "003", "001", "002"],
    "output_result": ["FAIL", "SUCCESS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "SUCCESS"],
    },
    columns=["case_id", "output_date", "output_carId", "output_result"],
    )
    input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "case_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "input_date": ["2021-01-20", "2021-02-21", "2020-02-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-09-05"],
    "input_carId": ["001", "001", "003", "001", "002"],
    },
    columns=["case_id", "input_date", "input_carId"],
    )
    
 
    
    def func(x, old_input):
    # print(old_input)
    mask = x['output_result'] == 'FAIL'
    count = mask.sum()
    indexes = x.loc[mask]
    # print(indexes.index)
    arr = np.arange(1, count + 1) * 7
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    td = pd.to_timedelta(arr, unit='d')
    old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date'] = pd.to_datetime(old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date']) + td
    old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date'] = pd.to_datetime(old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date']).dt.date
    return old_input
    
    
    **new_input** = output_df.groupby('output_carId').apply(lambda x: func(x, input_df))
    print(new_input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On here, why did you use the groupby? It is don't need to use.
Although the dataframe is big, the mask will be used at first, so it will be not problem.

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "case_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "output_date": ["2021-01-20", "2021-02-21", "2020-02-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-09-05"],
        "output_carId": ["001", "001", "003", "001", "002"],
        "output_result": ["FAIL", "SUCCESS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "SUCCESS"],
    },
    columns=["case_id", "output_date", "output_carId", "output_result"]
)

input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "case_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "input_date": ["2021-01-20", "2021-02-21", "2020-02-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-09-05"],
        "input_carId": ["001", "001", "003", "001", "002"],
    },
    columns=["case_id", "input_date", "input_carId"]
)

def func(x, old_input):
    mask = x['output_result'] == 'FAIL'
    count = mask.sum()
    if count == 0:
        return old_input
    indexes = x.loc[mask]
    while True:
        arr = np.arange(1, count + 1) * 7
        np.random.shuffle(arr)
        td = pd.to_timedelta(arr, unit='d')
        delta_date = pd.to_datetime(old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date']) + td
        delta_date = pd.to_datetime(delta_date).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date'] = delta_date
        new_dates = delta_date.unique()
        old_dates = old_input['input_date'].unique()
        if np.any(np.in1d(new_dates, old_dates)):
            break
    return old_input

group_by = output_df.groupby('output_carId', group_keys=False)
input_len = input_df.__len__()
group_len = group_by.groups.__len__()
apply_input = group_by.apply(lambda x: func(x, input_df))
new_input = apply_input[input_len * (group_len - 1):input_len * group_len]
print(new_input)
```

Result is

```
   case_id  input_date input_carId
0        1  2021-02-03         001
1        2  2021-02-21         001
2        3  2020-02-15         003
3        4  2020-01-28         001
4        5  2020-09-05         002
```

Comment: 15 lines means the repeat print result.
Maybe, it will be good to return when the last group in your function from group index argument

Comment: thank you; but the issue is that I need to check for unique dates within each group which has failed cases. right now this solution only  adds the rows to the input dataframe and then that's it

Comment: I updated for unique date and duplicated dataframe printing

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a full dataframe  during each iteration of the groupby. Can you just use this? Run what's in the function standalone and not do the groupby.

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "case_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "output_date": ["2021-01-20", "2021-02-21", "2020-02-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-09-05"],
    "output_carId": ["001", "001", "003", "001", "002"],
    "output_result": ["FAIL", "SUCCESS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "SUCCESS"],
    },
    columns=["case_id", "output_date", "output_carId", "output_result"],
    )

input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "case_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "input_date": ["2021-01-20", "2021-02-21", "2020-02-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-09-05"],
    "input_carId": ["001", "001", "003", "001", "002"],
    },
    columns=["case_id", "input_date", "input_carId"],
    )

mask = output_df['output_result'] == 'FAIL'
count = mask.sum()
indexes = output_df.loc[mask]
# print(indexes.index)
arr = np.arange(1, count + 1) * 7
np.random.shuffle(arr)
td = pd.to_timedelta(arr, unit='d')
old_input = input_df
old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date'] = pd.to_datetime(old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date']) + td
old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date'] = pd.to_datetime(old_input.loc[indexes.index, 'input_date']).dt.date
old_input
```

This is the new 'old_ouput' (not sure I understand your nomencalture....). Excuse the formatting coming from jupyter notebook

```
case_id input_date  input_carId
0   1   2021-02-03  001
1   2   2021-02-21  001
2   3   2020-02-29  003
3   4   2020-01-14  001
4   5   2020-09-05  002
```

Comment: can you check the unique() part? - right now we are not sure the dates are unique within each group

Comment: hi, did @Song's solution work? if so, mark that answer as correct.

Comment: it did but thnks for your help!